# Need to unlock the machine several time in the course of a session

Tags: login, password

It is irksome to have to unlock the system every few minutes for a single home user. After a few minutes idle time the screen switches off and needs password to reopen.  Can't there be a screen saver arrangement instead?  Is there any thing I can do to so configure my system?

Answer (score 2):

```
menu -> System -> Preferences -> Screensaver
```

Uncheck "Lock screen when screensaver is active", and voila!

(note that you can also set the time until screensaver activates etc.)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the *exact* wording, as I don't have the text of the English UI in front of me; it's the second checkbox on that screen.